# Draw on Java console two squares (one inside of the other)

Tags: java, console, drawing

basically I need to input two numbers and they will be the side size of two squares (drawn one inside of the other, being the inside square positioned in the middle of the biggest square).

I really have no idea how to do this, and the only thing that I was able to come up with was inputing a value and having one drawn square:

```
package teste;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private static Scanner sc;

public static void main(String a[])
{
        int size=0;

        System.out.print("Enter size: ");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        size = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i <= size; i++){

        for(int j=1; j <= size; j++){

            if(i==1 || i==size || j==1 || j==size)
            System.out.print("*");
            else
            System.out.print(" ");
                        }

        System.out.println();
                        }
}       
  }
```

I know it is not much, but my java skills are limited. Can you guys show a way to do it? I have no idea how to draw the square inside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean drawn one inside of the other? Does the smaller square have to be centered, or just anywhere in the middle? And this has to be an ASCII square? Not one drawn on a Swing component?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Yeah, the smaller square has to be centered. Like this picture: http://mathforum.org/blogs/max/files/2011/06/squarewin.png The image can only be drawn with stars.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i see is just make a buffer where you will fill the characters you want to draw in console

```
    // init buffer
    char buffer[][] = new char[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        buffer[i] = new char[size];
    }

    // borders of first square
    final int sq1Start = 0;
    final int sq1End = size-1;

    // draw outer square
    for(int i = sq1Start; i <= sq1End; i ++){
        for (int j = sq1Start; j <= sq1End; j ++) {
            if (i == sq1Start || i == sq1End || j == sq1Start || j == sq1End) {
                buffer[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    // borders of second square
    final int sq2Start = size / 4;
    final int sq2End = size * 3 / 4;

    // draw inner square
    for (int i = sq2Start; i <= sq2End; i++) {
        for (int j = sq2Start; j <= sq2End; j++) {
            if (i == sq2Start || i == sq2End || j == sq2Start || j == sq2End) {
                buffer[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j ++) {
            System.out.print(buffer[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Hope it would be helpful

Comment: hi Alexander, thanks a lot for your answer! I unfortunately did not quite get how your code is supposed to work. So I declare all the variables you put in your code and also user scanner version to input the values? Thank you so much once again.